# Liferay: Capture the event for "define permissions" of a Role

Tags: model, liferay, listener, hook, portlet

Can you please help me to capture the event for "define permissions" of a Role.

## Steps

1. Goto Control Panel, and select Roles
2. Select a Role and select "Define Permissions"
3. Define any permission for that role and Save.

How to capture this event in Model Listener.

Comment: IMHO it is a strange request, why do you need this kind of listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event can be caught by implementing and registering a model listener for the ResourcePermission model class which implements the following method:

```
public class ResourcePermissionModelListener extends BaseModelListener<ResourcePermission> {
    public void on{Before/After}Update(ResourcePermission model) throws ModelListenerException {}
}
```